# Excluding thirdparties from CMake generated Visual Studio solution

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I'm building a project that includes my own source code, but also includes a number of thirdparties e.g googletest.  I'm including third parties as source and adding them to my own `CMakeLists.txt` (via `add_subdirectory`) file so they get built alongside my libraries.

Is it possible to exclude the thirdparty projects from the generated Visual Studio solution?  I don't want developers of my own code to see the thirdparty projects/source when they open the solution, I just want it there at build time.

I'm aware I can move them so a separate folder in Visual Studio using the `FOLDER` property, but ideally don't want them showing at all.

Comment: No, it is not possible... you are vendoring 3rd party code. CMake doesn't care who wrote it, it is all 1st party from CMake's perspective. Add this to the list of reasons to not use `FetchContent` / `add_subdirectory`... if you have a dependency, declare it with `find_package`.

Comment: @AlexReinking yes got it, I was seeing this pattern more and more, but will revert to building thirdparty outside of my project and then including it pre-built